# How to convert retina canvas to non-retina display

Tags: ios, xcode, html5-canvas

Learning objective c programming and struck with this question: is it possible to convert a retina display canvas to non-retina display ?  How to make canvas both retina and non-retina display compatible ?

Comment: What do you mean with canvas app? Are you user HTML 5 canvas?

Comment: possible replicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232979/support-retina-displays-on-html5-canvas-game

Comment: I think, i failed to express my problem. I have developed an app for retina 4 full screen display(iphone 5) using storyboard. Now i want to make it usable for retina 3.5.Can anyone tell me please how it can be done?

Comment: Can anyone tell me is there a way out?

Answer (score 1):

if you have images that display called image.png then added a second image called image@2x.png

image@2x.png should be double the size of image.png

so when the app loads and discovers it has a retina screen it will look for @2x files before display your normal ones so that display retina images

Comment: Is this behavior documented anywhere? This cannot be for **all** HDPI screens, right? Just Apple ones? Doesn't this mean that those devices make an extra HTTP request for every image?

Comment: Only embedded app resources in iOS/Mac apps.